# React Native inconsistent rendering?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm writing an application in React Native and testing it out on an iOS simulator.

For some reason, the rendering behavior is inconsistent when refreshing via Metro (see the below screenshots). Is something wrong with the way I've programmed my app? I have a component that looks like this:

```
import React from "react";
import MapView from "react-native-maps";
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import MapDetail from "./MapDetail";
import { SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_WIDTH } from "./constants";

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    map: {
        position: 'relative',
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        width: SCREEN_WIDTH,
        height: SCREEN_HEIGHT,
    }
});

export default () => {
    return (
        <MapView
            style={styles.map}
            showsUserLocation={true}
        >
            <MapDetail />
        </MapView>
    );
};
```

Where `<MapDetail />` is:

```
import React  from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { PADDING, SCREEN_WIDTH } from "./constants";

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        bottom: 50,
        position: 'absolute',
        width: SCREEN_WIDTH,
        padding: PADDING,
    },
    card: {
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        height: 200,
        padding: PADDING,
        width: '100%',
    },
    text: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: 'red',
        fontSize: 20,
    }
});

export default () => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.card}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>
                    Hello world!
                </Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
};
```

`SCREEN_WIDTH` and `SCREEN_HEIGHT` are pulled from `Dimensions.get('window');`.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try adding `bottom : 0` to styles.card  and see

Comment: @Maneesh nope, still inconsistent

Comment: what you have in padding???

Comment: `PADDING = 16;`

Comment: Between you can directly give `position : absolute` to card, no need of parent view

Comment: Can you try by directly like without container??

Answer (score 0):

try outside MapDetail from `MapView` and use `height: "100%", width: "100%"`

```js
<View style={{flex:1}}>

   <MapView style={{height: "100%", width: "100%", flex:1}}>
   </MapView>

   <View style={{
        position : 'absolute',
        bottom : 0,
        width: '100%',
        padding : 16,
      }}>
         <MapDetail />
   </View>

</View>
```